# how to count length of the JSON array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to count the length of the JSON array element. I know to count the length of array using `json.array.length`. That is need to find that how many items in every index.

If my array is:

```
{
  "shareInfo": [{
      "id": "1",
      "a": "sss",
      "b": "sss",
      "question": "whi?"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "a": "sss",
      "b": "sss",
      "question": "whi?"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "a": "sss",
      "b": "sss",
      "question": "whi?"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "a": "sss",
      "b": "sss",
      "question": "whi?"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I need to find the length of `{"id":"1","a":"sss","b":"sss","question":"whi?"}`. In this there have four items. I tried this with `data.shareInfo[i].length`. But it produces error.

Please anyone tell me how to find the length.... Thanks....

Comment: Is this in JSON, or an actual array?

Comment: there's no such thing as a json array. there's json **STRINGS**. if it's an array, then it's native javascript and not "json".

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Before going to answer read this [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) once. Then you clearly understand the answer.

Try this It may work for you.

```
Object.keys(data.shareInfo[i]).length
```

Comment: it is only supported for IE9+ ...

Answer (score 19):

First if the object you're dealing with is a string then you need to parse it then figure out the length of the keys :

```
obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
shareInfoLen = Object.keys(obj.shareInfo[0]).length;
```

Comment: It produces the error `shareInfo` is not defined. But I have the array  called `shareInfo`

Comment: @ahjmorton your answer is correct for `javascript` arrays. If it is json array then it must be `Object.keys(data.shareInfo[i]).length`

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string format that can be used as a representation of a Javascript object literal.

Since JSON is a string, Javascript will treat it like a string, and not like an object (or array or whatever you are trying to use it as.)

Here is a good JSON reference to clarify this difference:

http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

So if you need accomplish the task mentioned in your question, you must convert the JSON string to an object or deal with it as a string, and not as a JSON array. There are several libraries to accomplish this.  Look at http://www.json.org/js.html for a reference.

Comment: You are right. But we can pass the values from server by using JSONarray. For archive this we need to create `JSONarray` ->>then `toJsonTree` Then we can convert the `object` to `String`. In client side we will receive result as above .( as array in the question).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
data = {"shareInfo":[{"id":"1","a":"sss","b":"sss","question":"whi?"},
{"id":"2","a":"sss","b":"sss","question":"whi?"},
{"id":"3","a":"sss","b":"sss","question":"whi?"},
{"id":"4","a":"sss","b":"sss","question":"whi?"}]};

ShareInfoLength = data.shareInfo.length;
alert(ShareInfoLength);
for(var i=0; i<ShareInfoLength; i++)
{
alert(Object.keys(data.shareInfo[i]).length);
}
```