# How to count the object inside the JsonArray?

Tags: java, json, java-8, gson

Below Json format is my input, i need to count the total based on Object

```
Students:[
        {
        "Student_id": "101"
        "Name": "Jon",
        "Course" : "Engineer"
        },
        {
        "Student_id": "102"
        "Name": "Snow",
        "Course" : "Medical"
        },
        {
        "Student_id": "103"
        "Name": "Walter",
        "Course" : "Chemistry"
        },
        {
        "Student_id": "104"
        "Name": "White",
        "Course" : "Chemistry"
        }
    ]
```

When i loop the JsonArray Am not able to count the total?? it will show always count 1,i want output like below format

```
No Of Students: 4
Total Chemistry Students :2
```

Below code i tried,

```
            JsonArray Students=Details.getAsJsonArray("Students");

            for(int i=0;i<Students.size();i++)
            {
                JsonObject Std=Students.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                String SrdID=Std.get("Student_id").getAsString();

                System.out.println("Student Details----"+SrdID);
            }


            String [] Studentarr=new String[] {"Student_id"};
            int Count=Studentarr.length;

            System.out.println("Count ---"+ Count);
```

Any Help will be Appreciate!! Thanks In Advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: *When i loop the JsonArray Am not able to count the total?? it will show always count 1* -- Share the code that *apparently* does this. Also, which json library are you using?

Comment: @NicholasK Gson

Comment: show the code whatever you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know the structure for each element in the array is the same, could you create a Student class and have an array of Student objects?

In my experience, it's always better to manipulate objects than pure json, but you've not said in your question if that is a requirement or not, so I'll assume it is.

Therefore, you may find the answer on this similar question useful:
[how to count length of the JSON array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209136/how-to-count-length-of-the-json-array-element)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

With this structure:

```
var object = {"Students":[
    {
    "Student_id": "101",
    "Name": "Jon",
    "Course" : "Engineer"
    },
    {
    "Student_id": "102",
    "Name": "Snow",
    "Course" : "Medical"
    },
    {
    "Student_id": "103",
    "Name": "Walter",
    "Course" : "Chemistry"
    },
    {
    "Student_id": "104",
    "Name": "White",
    "Course" : "Chemistry"
    }]};
```

Now, we can try with JS this:

```
print(object.Students.length) // print total
print(object.Students.filter(st => st.Course === 'Chemistry').length) // print occurrences
```

Output is:

```
> 4
> 2
```

Comment: in java we cant pass the pass  st => st.Course === 'Chemistry').length  in stream like this coz its not accepted 'Chemistry' it will accept single Char 'e'