# Count and loop through JSON object of arrays

Tags: javascript, json, protractor

I get issues when I want to loop through a JSON array of objects.

**Issues such as:**

- It only counts two (I assume because of they Object.keys) and I have two keys.
- Loops with only one value

**My code:**

```
var codes = require('./nl.json');
for (var i = 0, l = Object.keys(codes).length; i <= l; i++) {
    console.log(l) ;
    var areaCodeTest = codes.netherlands[i].areaCode;
    var areaNameTest = codes.netherlands[i].areaName;

    it("Search for postal code ", function(){
        var postCode = element(by.id("imysearchstring"));
        postCode.click(); 
        browser.sleep(1000); 
        console.log(areaCodeTest);
        postCode.clear().sendKeys(areaCodeTest);
        browser.sleep(1000);
        console.log("Typed " + areaCodeTest);
    });
}
```

**My Json (Short example):**

```
{
"netherlands": [
  {
    "areaCode": 9401,
    "areaName": "Assen"
  },
  {
    "areaCode": 9402,
    "areaName": "Assen"
  },
  {
    "areaCode": 9403,
    "areaName": "Assen"
  }
 ]
}
```

I have looked at answers such as :

[Size of Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756104/get-size-of-json-object/6756305) and
[Length of Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209136/how-to-count-length-of-the-json-array-element)

**I have tried:**

```
(var i = 0, l = Object.keys(codes).length; i <= l; i++)

(var i = 0, l = Object.keys(codes.netherlands[0]).length; i <= l; i++)

for (var i = 0, l = codes.netherlands.length; i <= l; i++) // uses last areaCode in json file and only loop with that number. It does not start from top.
```

**Image:**
[some of my outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxTWR.jpg)

**Expected:**
What I want is to count amount of ofjects in JSON (Not the key/values)

Loop through all data and assign them to `var areaCodeTest = codes.netherlands[i].areaCode;` and `var areaNameTest = codes.netherlands[i].areaName;`

Comment: Do you just want the length of the array? if so, it should be `codes.netherlands.length` in your case

Comment: @ShakedDahan it then loops only using one areaCode (8245) - Last record in JSON file.
I want it to start from the top and go through each object and use areaName and areaCode

Comment: why don&#39;t you use a more comfy loop? Object.keys(codes).forEach(function (item) {  console.log(item); // key  console.log(codes[areaCode]; // value });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by using the following:

```
var codes = require('./nl.json');

codes.forEach((item) => {
    var areaCodeTest = item.areaCode;
    var areaNameTest = item.areaName;

    it("and search for postal code ", function(){
        var postCode = element(by.id("imysearchstring"));
        postCode.click(); 
        console.log(areaCodeTest);
        postCode.clear().sendKeys(areaCodeTest);
        browser.sleep(1000);
        console.log("Typed " + areaCodeTest);
    });
}
```

I am not a 100% what the `=>` means near the foreach  but I am currently researching why my code works. If you know please post a comment so that other developers also learn.

This let me think of the meme "not sure why code does not work / Not sure why code works"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the actual key in your loop in order to access `codes[key]`

Simplified version of your `for()` loop with stored variable for the object keys or using `for in` loop

```js
const keys = Object.keys(codes)

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  // current object key and value of that property in main object
  const key = keys[i], arr = codes[key];
  console.log(`key = ${key}, length= ${arr.length}`)

  // do another loop here for `arr` if needed
}

// OR using `for in`
for (let key in codes) {
  console.log(`key = ${key}, length= ${codes[key].length}`)
}
```

```html
<script>
  const codes = {
    "netherlands": [{
        "areaCode": 9401,
        "areaName": "Assen"
      },
      {
        "areaCode": 9402,
        "areaName": "Assen"
      },
      {
        "areaCode": 9403,
        "areaName": "Assen"
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this I give you a sample

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

var length = (Object.keys(object1).length);
```

Please Refer this Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys